# Combining all possible options from a dict

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following dict:

```
d = {
    'option1': range(0, 5),
    'optionA': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'extra_option': range(100, 200, 20)
}
```

I'm looking for code that would provide me with an array like so:

```
[ "--option1=0 --optionA=a --extra_option=100",
  "--option1=0 --optionA=a --extra_option=120",
  "--option1=0 --optionA=a --extra_option=140",
  .
  .
  .
  "--option1=5 --optionA=b --extra_option=180"]
```

I've looked at itertools product and combination, but both seem not the right tool for the job. I was trying to create a generator like so:

```
def get_options(d, keys):
    key = keys.pop()
    for key in d:
        if len(keys) > 0:
            for value in d[key]:
                for other in get_options(d, keys[:]):
                    yield "--%s=%s %s" % (key, value, other)
        else:
            for value in d[key]:
                yield "--%s=%s" % (key, value)

for x in get_options(d, list(d.keys())):
        print (x)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
$ python3 test.py
--optionA=a --optionA=a --optionA=a
--optionA=a --optionA=a --optionA=b
--optionA=a --optionA=a --optionA=c
--optionA=a --optionA=a --option1=0
--optionA=a --optionA=a --option1=1
--optionA=a --optionA=a --option1=2
--optionA=a --optionA=a --option1=3
--optionA=a --optionA=a --option1=4
--optionA=a --optionA=a --extra_option=100
--optionA=a --optionA=a --extra_option=120
--optionA=a --optionA=a --extra_option=140
--optionA=a --optionA=a --extra_option=160
--optionA=a --optionA=a --extra_option=180
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    for x in get_options(d, list(d.keys())):
  File "test.py", line 12, in get_options
    for other in get_options(d, keys):
  File "test.py", line 12, in get_options
    for other in get_options(d, keys):
  File "test.py", line 8, in get_options
    key = keys.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Which is not what I was expecting... What am I doing wrong? Can anyone tell me about a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Edit 10 seconds later:

Argh, so I still had the `for key in d` in there from a previous test... Removing that (and de-indenting the rest a bit), it works! But my other question remains, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: if you have a working but you want to improve it, consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, Python has provided the similar function called `itertools.product`.`itertools` packages lots of useful tool for iterated task, such as combinations, combinations_and_replacement, chain etc.

The `product` will return Cartesian product of input iterables.

That's something like this:

```
product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
```

So you just need to return the changed in every round with `product`.And time complexity will be O(n)!

Here is my improved code:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import OrderedDict


d = {
    'option1': range(0, 5),
    'optionA': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'extra_option': range(100, 200, 20)
}


#just make it beautiful
def ordered(d):
    temp = OrderedDict()
    for key, value in d.items():
        temp[key] = value
    return temp


def merge(d):
    dKeys = list(ordered(d).keys())
    keyStr = "={} --".join(dKeys)
    keyStr = "--" + keyStr + "={}"
    dValues = [list(value) for value in d.values()]
    for value_list in product(*dValues):
        yield keyStr.format(*value_list)

for r in merge(d):
    print(r)
```

Comment: And the code will be clearer.  I advise you read the official doc if you wanna learn more about `itertools`. (PS:I consider it the hardest part in your question to format the `keyStr` with simple code)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for the OP, but want to leave this here as it is very versatile and useful.  I think the cleanest way to achieve what the OP is trying to do is using itertools.products to create an iterator which yields dicts with each combination as:

```
d = { 'option1': range(0, 5),
      'optionA': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      'extra_option': range(100, 200, 20) }

def dict2combinations (dict_in):
    for combination in product(*dict_in.values()):
        d = dict(zip(dict_in.keys(), combination))
        yield d

for c in dict2combinations(d):
    print (c)
```

which returns:

> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 0, 'optionA': 'a'}
> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 0, 'optionA': 'b'}
> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 0, 'optionA': 'c'}
> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 1, 'optionA': 'a'}
> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 1, 'optionA': 'b'}
> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 1, 'optionA': 'c'}
> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 2, 'optionA': 'a'}
> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 2, 'optionA': 'b'}
> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 2, 'optionA': 'c'}
> {'extra_option': 100, 'option1': 3, 'optionA': 'a'}

This answer was inspired from http://stephantul.github.io/python/2019/07/20/product-dict/